# .NET application not reflecting ShellRunAs (netonly) credentials

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, vpn

I have an  angularJS application that calls API service. On each service call API authenticates the user using `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity`. 
The requirement is that I should be connected to a VPN and should be able to run the application with different credentials (specific to the VPN I am connected to) using ShellRunAs (netonly).

Both the client side application and API service are in the same VS solution. I run Visual studio 2012 premium with the new credentials using ShellRunAs (netonly). Then I open the solution in that. When I run the solution, it starts and makes API call. When I debug in the API call, I get my original domain credentials in `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity` instead of the credentials used to open Visual studio with.

Authentication mode is Windows. IIS express is used while debugging. I have tried setting applicationHost.config entries in IISExpress > config to enable impersonation. I have also tried opening the browser with the new credentials. No use.

How do I get the new credentials in API?